# Prolog Parse Tree a^n b^n

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to make a parse tree for language a^n b^n.

Below is what I've tried, but it just turns true without priting the parse tree.

```
%% a^n, b^n.        ex) s([a,a,b,b],[]). = true

s --> a,s,b.
s --> [].

s(ab(S)) --> a,s(S),s.
s([]) --> [].
```

For example, I'd like to print `ab(ab([]))` if I type `s(T,[a,a,b,b],[]).`

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

`s(ab(S)) --> a,s(S),s.` should be `s(ab(S)) --> [a],s(S),[b].` which will give you the correct results:

```
s([]) --> [].
s(ab(S)) --> [a], s(S), [b].

| ?- phrase(s(L), [a,a,b,b]).

L = ab(ab([])) ? ;

no
| ?- phrase(s(ab(ab([]))), L).

L = [a,a,b,b]

yes
| ?- phrase(s(L), T).

L = []
T = [] ? ;

L = ab([])
T = [a,b] ? ;

L = ab(ab([]))
T = [a,a,b,b] ? ;

L = ab(ab(ab([])))
T = [a,a,a,b,b,b] ? ;

L = ab(ab(ab(ab([]))))
T = [a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b] ? ;
...
```